# What after cloning repository from redmine

Tags: git, github, repository, redmine

i'm worked on upgrade Prestashop (downloaded from ftp, without .git files) and it's well done. Now i get infmriation then i need to do synchro with git repository. So i created empty catalog in htdocs and i use

> $ git clone ssh://git@redmine.[...].com/[...].git

After repository is downladed i go into this catalog and i have a couple of files but it's no prestashop files like mine, only hidden .git folder (1.5 GB). What should i do now to send information about all changes to remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i missed `[-b <name>]` as option :-)